# How do I merge two objects while omitting null values with lodash

Tags: javascript, object, merge, lodash

I've researched how to merge two JavaScript objects while omitting null values, so far I've tried using merge, assign, clone without success.

Here is my test ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9upjf4bc/)) :

```
let defaultValues = {code: '', price: 0, description: ''}
let product = {code: 'MyCode', price: null, description: 'Product Description'}

//Merge two objects
let merged = _.merge({}, defaultValues, product)
console.log(merged)

//My result
{code: 'MyCode', price: null, description: 'Product Description'}

//My expected result
{code: 'MyCode', price: 0, description: 'Product Description'}
```

I use VueJS framework, when I have these null properties on some inputs (with v-model), I receive an exception.

Thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use [`_.mergeWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mergeWith):

```
let merged = _.mergeWith(
    {}, defaultValues, product,
    (a, b) => b === null ? a : undefined
)
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9upjf4bc/1/)

Comment: Why do we pass an empty object as the first parameter?

Comment: @Ernest: `merge` and `mergeWith` modify and return their first argument, rather than creating a new object and returning that.